# How to turn on Silverlight security prompt?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, prompt

I am using a silverlight control on an MVC website to capture the snap using webcam. Wen this control is loaded, it asks for some security permissions. This was working fine, i have used it many times, until i check the box saying "Remember my answer...."(Shown below). The control is not loading now, it says "Silverlight Plug-In has crashed".

How can i rollback this decision?. Is there any flag in windows or is there any control related issue?. The silverlight control is not written by me so i don't know what is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know I have run across this many times before and someone had finally figured out how to do this but wouldn't you know I cannot find it anymore. Seems like you could delete the application setting (in your browser) or a cookie or something. Either way, this question on SU will help you fix it too, just not as nice.

[Browser / silverlight configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/456323/browser-silverlight-configuration)